# While reading a text file, using a for line in file loop, how to select the previous line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's a sample code

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        find = 'some string'
        if find in line:
            if previous line is the same as this line: #how to write this ?
                pass
            else:
                print(line)
```

How to write line 5 in this code ?

Comment: Alternatively, instead of looking back, make a note when a line contains your string and check whether the next one does, too.

Answer (score 1):

Save the previous line at each iteration:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as file:
    previous = None
    find = 'n'
    for line in file:
        if find in line:
            if line != previous:
                print(line)
        previous = line
```

Sample input:

```
hello
no
no
hello
```

Output:

```
no
```